# How to find the sum of a string in a list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I have a list like this

```
['MGM', '1'], ['MGD', '1'], ['V1', '[0,2,0,1]'], ['AuD', '[0,0,0,1]']
```

in python. I want to find the sum of the lists that are strings like this:

```
['MGM', '1'], ['MGD', '1'], ['V1', '3'], ['AuD', '1']
```

Should I convert them to lists within the lists first? If so how would I go about this?

Trying my best to learn how to code for science.

Comment: Is your first example a list of lists?

Comment: @AnandSKumar he seems to be saying that they are all strings. So it is a list of strings. However, sometimes the string represents a list.

Comment: @TonyIto What have you tried? Is there a particular problem you are having? Best to publish your code and get comments rather than expect us to write it all for you.

Comment: @RobertB No, it would be a list of list of strings (according to the example) , that is why i asked if its a list of lists.

Comment: Hi @ Anand S Kumar , I am too a learner of python , But have seen you helping out people here, How can i reach you directly for some problems ,

Answer (score 7):

Given:

```
s = [['MGM', '1'], ['MGD', '1'], ['V1', '[0,2,0,1]'], ['AuD', '[0,0,0,1]']]
```

The following will convert the second items to Python objects:

```
import ast
for sublist in s:
    sublist[1] = ast.literal_eval(sublist[1])
```

Result:

```
[['MGM', 1], ['MGD', 1], ['V1', [0, 2, 0, 1]], ['AuD', [0, 0, 0, 1]]]
```

Then convert them back with special handling for lists:

```
for sublist in s:
    if isinstance(sublist[1],list):
        sublist[1] = sum(sublist[1])
    sublist[1] = str(sublist[1])
```

Result:

```
[['MGM', '1'], ['MGD', '1'], ['V1', '3'], ['AuD', '1']]
```

Comment: The first step can be done by: `map(lambda t: [t[0], eval(t[1])], lst)` as well

Comment: @alfasin, `eval` use is discouraged since it can execute damaging Python code.

Answer (score 4):

This should do what you want. Explanation is in the comments.

```
import ast

# Create the list
myList = [['MGM', '1'], ['MGD', '1'], ['V1', '[0,2,0,1]'], ['AuD', '[0,0,0,1]']]

# Loop through each sublist
for num in myList:
    # try to convert the string to a list and sum it
    try:
        # This works by evaluating the string into a list object
        # Then summing the numbers in the list
        # then turning that number back into a string so it's like the rest
        num[1] = str(sum(ast.literal_eval(num[1])))
    # If it fails, it must just be a number, so ignore
    except TypeError:
        pass

print myList
```

Comment: 1. you forgot the wrapping list in the declaration of `my_list`. 2. you probably meant: `num[1] = str(sum(ast.literal_eval(num[1]))) + ''  ` because you can't append an `int` to a `str`. Fix these two and you'll get my upvote.

Comment: @alfasin for what it's worth, the appending of a string to the int converts it back, but I did update it. Your way is better.

Comment: @David, not in Python: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'`

Comment: @MarkTolonen is that a 3.x rule? Working in my 2.7.9 setup.

Comment: @David, check more closely.  It throws a `TypeError` that is hidden by your `try/except`.  Just try `1 + ''` in the interpreter.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> s = [['MGM', '1'], ['MGD', '1'], ['V1', '[0,2,0,1]'], ['AuD', '[0,0,0,1]']]
```

Since your data is a disaster, we'll use a helper function for the sum

```
>>> def mysum(L):
...     try:
...         return sum(L)
...     except TypeError:
...         return L
...
```

can use JSON or literal_eval to decode the strings

```
>>> import json
>>> [[i, str(mysum(json.loads(j)))] for i, j in s]
[['MGM', '1'], ['MGD', '1'], ['V1', '3'], ['AuD', '1']]
```

Comment: thank you very very much. yes, it is a disaster and I will learn from this.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a list of list of strings, you can can do this in one line , by using [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) (to evaluate the string as a list) and then using `sum()` on it. Example -

```
lst1 = [[a, (str(sum(ast.literal_eval(b))) if b.startswith('[') else b)] for a,b in lst]
```

Though its a bit unreadable. A bit more readable version using `for` loops -

```
lst1 = []
for a,b in lst:
    if b.startswith('['):
        lst1.append([a, (str(sum(ast.literal_eval(b)))])
    else:
        lst1.append([a,b])
```

Demo -

```
>>> lst = [['MGM', '1'], ['MGD', '1'], ['V1', '[0,2,0,1]'], ['AuD', '[0,0,0,1]']]
>>> import ast
>>> lst1 = [[a, (str(sum(ast.literal_eval(b))) if b.startswith('[') else b)] for a,b in lst]
>>> lst1
[['MGM', '1'], ['MGD', '1'], ['V1', '3'], ['AuD', '1']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Code:

```
from ast import literal_eval
los=[['MGM', '1'], ['MGD', '1'], ['V1', '[0,2,0,1]'], ['AuD', '[0,0,0,1]']]
for lst in los :
    if '[' in lst[1]:
        lst[1]=sum(literal_eval(lst[1]))
print los
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Mark, No one mentioned `eval` !

```
lst = [['MGM', '1'], ['MGD', '1'], ['V1', '[0,2,0,1]'], ['AuD', '[0,0,0,1]']]
for sublist in lst:
    sublist[1] = eval(sublist[1])
for sublist in lst:
    if isinstance(sublist[1],list):
        sublist[1] = sum(sublist[1])
    sublist[1] = str(sublist[1])
print lst
```

Another one can be-

```
lst = [['MGM', '1'], ['MGD', '1'], ['V1', '[0,2,0,1]'], ['AuD', '[0,0,0,1]']]

for x in lst:
    x[1] = str(sum([int(i) for i in x[1].replace("[","").replace("]","").split(',')]))

print lst
```

it prints

```
[['MGM', '1'], ['MGD', '1'], ['V1', '3'], ['AuD', '1']]
```

Comment: Except for @alfasin. Anyway `eval` should be your _last_ choice for stuff like this

Comment: the values appear to be json-compatible. Why don't use a json parsing library?